# Getting a tag line number in browser

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get line number of a certain tag using JavaScript?

For example, if I have the following HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      x = "<script>"
    </script>
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then:

- head tag is on line 3
- title tag is on line 4
- body tag is on line 5
- script tag is on line 7 and 10

Perhaps something like `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].lineNumber`?

Comment: There are no simple&beautiful ways to do it via JavaScript/DOM, e.g. there are no methods/properties like you've suggested. But see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2044642/2170192) for possible solutions/workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Once the HTML has been through a DOM parser, any link to the source code is discarded.

You would have to refetch the HTML and then parse it yourself, keeping track of the line numbers as you go.