# Display the source code line number of an html tag onClick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to record the source code line number for an HTML tag when I click on it. For example, if there are two tags, recording the tag alone will not help me differenciate between them.

Here is an example. Two "H1" tags:

[image]

When I click on the first, I want to know the source code line number:

[image]

If I could know that the second H1 was line number 74 (for example), I could know that the first and second H1 tags are not the same when recorded in the database.

Comment: You can't exactly 'get' line number, you can get the source, count the number of newlines till the element that matches certain attributes but the 'line number' doesn't actually exist

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do this, but I don't believe it's possible. You could try to infer line number by interrogating the DOM and counting line breaks, but that's clumsy and probably far from cross-browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044642/finding-out-what-line-number-an-element-in-the-dom-occurs-on-in-javascript

Comment: I'm looking for a clear way to differenciate elements on a page where only knowing the tags could produce similar results for a separate action. For example, in the above screenshot, there are two H1 tags (not necessarily hrefs) that if clicked on separately and the clicks were recorded in a database under the H1 tags alone, they would look like the same item clicked on when they were actually separate objects clicked on. I want a way to differentiate two similarly styled items on a webpage from each other. Alternative ideas?

Comment: You make a great point bringing up the conflict with cross-browser... browsers could render the code differently and therefore numbers may not line up.

Comment: quick question... what font is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best suggestion would be to get the index of the element. It's really not clear what your full intent is. If you need a complete selector to find the exact same element again that can also be done.

```
$('h1').click(function(){
   alert($('h1').index(this);
});
```

A better description of your use case would help

For a much broader `all tags` approach:

```
$('*').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) { // prevent all ancestors being registered
        var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        var data = {
            tag: tag,
            index: $(tag).index(this);
        };
        // sending tracking data to server
        $.post('path/to/server', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you be comfortable showing me this in a FiddleJS demo(https://jsfiddle.net/) where it displays the path in a pop-up? I'd help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `displays path`?

Comment: I'm just asking for you to demonstrate your suggestion for "all tags".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add unique id names to them and detect that instead??

Something like:

HTML:

```
<h1 class="title" id="titleA">I'm a product designer by trade</h1>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer. Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer. Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer. Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer.</p>

<h1 class="title" id="titleB">I'm a viking warrior by trade</h1>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer. Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer. Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer. Lorem Ipsum is dummy text so I'm typing random paragraph texts for a StackOverflow Answer.</p>
```

JS:

```
$('#titleA').click(function(){
   alert("You clicked the first title Jamison!!");
});
$('#titleB').click(function(){
   alert("You clicked the second title Jamison!!");
});
```

Comment: Great point but what I'm looking for is a way to not need to tag items. For this very reason am I looking for alternate solutions. Tagging takes time and planning. If we could track and group page events based on individual attributes of an object on a page rather than creating unique tags requiring added interaction with the code, execution of tracking could be more easily implemented (hypothetically). Make sense?